# Rails 4 left outer join issue returning wrong records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, scope

I have 2 tables: appointments and doors. Door has one appointment and appointment belongs to a door. The appointments table have the door_id.

The query I wrote is:

```
scope :not_in_appointments, -> { joins("left outer join appointments on appointments.door_id = doors.id") }
```

ISSUE: The scope is still returning the doors that are in the appointments table.

GOAL: We want to get doors that are NOT in the appointments table.

The left outer join is suppose to do that. Can someone please let us know why this query is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: You're mistaken, a left outer join is not supposed to do that. A left outer join returns records that match plus those that don't match the table on the right. To get what you want, you need to left outer join, then filter out the matches, for example, by filtering for those where the join key is null.

Answer (score 0):

This works just as fine, adding an extra where clause to the scope:

```
scope :not_in_appointments, -> { joins("left outer join appointments on appointments.door_id = doors.id").where("appointments.id IS NULL") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try this one

```
scope :not_in_appointments, -> { where("id NOT IN (SELECT door_id FROM appointments)") }
```

The performance is much better than using 'left outer join' because we are reducing number of redundant records as soon as possible.